# Twitter app that supports real time updating

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation

Hi everyone i need a twitter client that fully integrates with the unity shell and is capable of providing real time updates for my mentions, direct messages etc when minimised

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter client with Real Time Notifications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139815/twitter-client-with-real-time-notifications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your specifications, I recommend you to use [Gwibber](http://gwibber.com/), which is default in 11.04.

[image]

**Integration in Unity**:

- Integrates with Message Indicator
- Quicklists in the launcher.
- **Real time updating**.  How*?

---

Real time updating?

Not by seconds, the minimum is 5 minutes to refresh for tweets and mentions and replies, but seriously do you need it to be faster?It will bring headache:).

And tick **show notifications for all messages**.

**Go to edit ---> preferences ---> set the minimum to 5 minutes.**
[image]

---

**Note**: If you really need real time updating; you can use [Tweetdeck](https://www.tweetdeck.com/) for desktop, but you need first to install Adobe Air. But it lacks integration with Unity and Ubuntu in general.