# Twitter client with Real Time Notifications?

Tags: software-recommendation, twitter

Is there a Twitter client (or just a utility) that pushes real time Twitter feed / mentions notifications? By real time, I mean notified as soon as the tweet is posted, like what [MetroTwit](http://www.metrotwit.com/) does in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Hotot's had support for user streams(aka real-time updates) since quite some time. If the [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cnfkkfleeiooolklkgkmigodkmcopnji) isn't not what you're looking at, you can install the native client.

It is available in [Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/hotot/), click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hotot) to install it

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try Polly, I think it's brilliant. Don't know whether it's real time but it's quick enough for me to not notice.

The launchpad site is here [Polly](https://launchpad.net/polly).

Or this is the PPA: **ppa:conscioususer/polly-unstable**

Just to note: It's currently in Alpha development stage but I haven't noticed any bugs as of yet.

Comment: It does support real time updates, as mentioned [here](https://launchpad.net/polly/+announcement/9182)

Answer (score 3):

The [Twitter Notifier extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ikknnkomiokeodcdkknnhgjmncfiefmn) for Chrome shows real time HTML5 desktop notifications.

Answer (score 2):

TweetDeck provides real time notifications too, but I transferred to Hotot because TweetDeck was too heavy an app for me and requires too much of a bandwidth with my poor internet connection.